# LWC - Styling the button

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

Quick question for the styling in LWC. This is styling in JS.

```
function changeVisibility() {
  document.getElementById("imgbox").style.visibility = "none";
}
```

And I'm trying to do this in LWC and have something like this(which won't work)

```
changeVisibility() {
  var retake = this.template.querySelector('imgbox');
  retake.style.display = "none";
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your query selector is likely wrong. Try:

```
var retake = this.template.querySelector('.imgbox');
```

Or query by almost any other property. Querying by `id` tends to be problematic, as the runtime modifies the values to make sure they're globally unique.

[Demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/2Bu2vzLcFRtLQvGilebw/src/app.js?p=stories).